# Records duplicated on SQL Join (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to return the results of subscribers who have been sent emails, when they've been sent, if they've opened/clicked and whether or not is house bounced/they've unsubscribed.

I'm using the following code which is working but it is creating duplicate rows rather than grouping by subscriber key and jobID;

```
SELECT
s.SubscriberKey, 
s.JobId, 
s.EventDate,
j.EmailName,
b.Bounces,
o.[Opens],
c.Clicks, 
u.Unsubscribed
FROM (SELECT 
    snt.SubscriberKey, 
    snt.JobId,
    snt.EventDate
 FROM _Sent snt
 GROUP BY snt.SubscriberKey, snt.JobID, snt.EventDate
) s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT JobID, COUNT(*) as [Bounces], bnc.SubscriberKey
    FROM [_Bounce] bnc
    GROUP BY bnc.JobID, bnc.SubscriberKey
) b
ON s.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) as [Opens], JobID
    FROM [_Open] op
GROUP BY op.SubscriberKey, op.JobID
) o
ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cl.JobID, COUNT(*) as [Clicks], cl.SubscriberKey
    FROM [_Click] cl
    GROUP BY cl.JobID, cl.SubscriberKey
) c
ON s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT un.JobID, 
  COUNT(*) AS [Unsubscribed], 
  un.SubscriberKey
  FROM [_Unsubscribe] un
  GROUP BY un.JobId, un.SubscriberKey
 ) u
ON s.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _Job j
ON s.JobId = j.JobId
```

For example, this returns;

| SubscriberKey | JobID | EventDate | EmailName | Bounces | Opens | Clicks | Unsubs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 14503 | 09/03/2022 | Example 1 | null | 2 | 4 | null |
| 001 | 14503 | 09/03/2022 | Example 1 | null | 1 | 2 | null |
| 002 | 14503 | 09/03/2022 | Example 1 | null | 3 | 4 | null |
| 001 | 14505 | 08/03/2022 | Example 2 | null | 1 | 0 | null |
| 001 | 14505 | 08/03/2022 | Example 2 | null | 1 | 3 | null |

What I'm struggling to achieve is grouping the rows by the subscriber key and the Job ID.

Is anybody able to support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're applying GROUP BY inside the Inner Queries, that's the reason. I'd first gather everything raw and then apply GROUP BY in the end.

```
SELECT
s.SubscriberKey, 
s.JobId, 
s.EventDate,
j.EmailName,
count(b.SubscriberKey) as Bounces,
count(o.SubscriberKey) as Opens,
count(c.SubscriberKey) as Clicks, 
count(u.SubscriberKey) as Unsubscribed
FROM (SELECT 
    snt.SubscriberKey, 
    snt.JobId,
    snt.EventDate
 FROM _Sent snt
 GROUP BY snt.SubscriberKey, snt.JobID, snt.EventDate
) s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT JobID, bnc.SubscriberKey
    FROM [_Bounce] bnc
) b
ON s.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey, JobID
    FROM [_Open] op
) o
ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cl.JobID, cl.SubscriberKey
    FROM [_Click] cl
) c
ON s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT un.JobID, 
  un.SubscriberKey
  FROM [_Unsubscribe] un
 ) u
ON s.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _Job j
ON s.JobId = j.JobId
group BY
s.SubscriberKey, 
s.JobId, 
s.EventDate,
j.EmailName
```

Comment: Thanks! That's resolved the issue.